# Is there a risk to run viral embedded macros on Ubuntu/LibreOffice?

Tags: malware, word-documents

Our small organization receives a lot of fake emails with .doc attachments containing VBA viral macros. Is there a risk to run these macros on LibreOffice / Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. However, the probability is lower. It's quite likely an exploit for MS Office won't affect LibreOffice and most .doc viruses will be for Office, but if an attacker knew what you're using, it's quite possible.

As an example, see this [link](http://linux.softpedia.com/blog/LibreOffice-Vulnerabilities-Closed-in-Ubuntu-14-10-Ubuntu-14-04-and-Ubuntu-12-04-479482.shtml).

If you want complete security, run a VM on your machine and open files there. And of course, never run LibreOffice as root.